# Why does this substitution with regular expression in postgresql not work?

Tags: postgresql

I cannot understand why this line is not working

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET "Raw_data"= regexp_replace("Raw_data", '\s', '_'
```

I just want to substitute all white spaces present on the the cell of the field "Raw_data" with an underscore
I have no error when the query runs but does not work..

Comment: What do you get if you `SELECT regexp_replace("Raw_data", '\s', '_') from <table_name>`? Also, what is your `standard_conforming_strings` set to?

Comment: the entire text. the output is like `SELECT "Raw_data" FROM <table_name>;`

Comment: Please check your column carefully, may be only  first space  is changed with underscore. Do you use global flag `g`?

Comment: It  works!! thanks you!!! :)